# angular 7 populate child object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

using Angular 7 developing a list/detail form
largely working off the angular dynamic form tutorial

i want to click on a row in the table and populate the child object.

the page is built up in this manner

```
documentListComponent   <! clicking on this should pop the detail >
documentDetailComponent   <! the detail has some header info and >=1 input fields>
     |- oneFieldDisplayComponent
```

I am able to click on a row and the detail is shown and it gets the data object. 
I can use {{}} notation in the header portion to demonstrate that this is working

the FieldGroup is getting returned from the dataService and the ngFor is correctly displaying empty controls...

What I can not figure out is how do I now use patchValue(or something else) to populate the controls w/ the  data object?

*) I can not seem to correctly 'grab' the detailComponent in the listComponent.ts so I could call a method...

*) The FieldGroup population is asynch, so I have to wait for that

**HOW CAN I POPULATE THE FIELDGROUP AFTER I CLICK ON A ROW IN THE LIST?**

(not sure my question is stated clearly. Ill take a step away and come back shortly. in the mean time... feel free to ask clarification questions...)

Here is an excerpt of the documentList

```
  <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Ver#</td>
              <td>Ver Name</td>
              <td>Locked</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
        <tr    *ngFor="let pa of paVers;index as idx"  (click)="onRowClicked($event, pa)" >
          <td style="width:15px;">{{pa.version}}</td>
          <td style="width:200px;">{{pa.versionName}}</td>
          <!--<td>{{pa | json}}</td>-->
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div style="padding-bottom:10px;">

      <div *ngIf="selectedpaVer" >show me</div>
      <app-property-analysis-detail *ngIf="selectedpaVer"
                                    [detailFormGroup]="listFormGroup"
                                    [paVer]="selectedpaVer" formControlName="detail" ></app-property-analysis-detail>

    </div>
```

an excerpt of my detail class is here

```
export class propertyAnalysisDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  fields: any[] = []; //these are the formFields we get from sbDocField service
                       //  will be based on template type

  @Input() detailFormGroup: FormGroup;
  @Input()paVer : propertyAnalysisVersion;
  @Output() emitPass: EventEmitter<propertyAnalysisVersion>= new EventEmitter<propertyAnalysisVersion>();

  constructor(private fieldService: sbDocFieldAPI
              , private sbDFservice: sbDocFieldService
              , private fb: FormBuilder) {
    var i: number;
    i = 3;
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.getAllDocFields();
    this.patchControls(this.paVer);

  }   

  getAllDocFields() {
    this.fieldService.getDocFields().subscribe(
      (data) => {
       console.log(data);
        //ask the data service for a list of fields ( this should be specific to a templateId)
        this.fields = data;

        //now turn those fields into a formGroup
        this.detailFormGroup = this.sbDFservice.toFormGroup(this.fields);
      });

  }   

  patchControls(paVer_ : propertyAnalysisVersion) {

    this.detailFormGroup.patchValue({
      propertyName: paVer_.propertyName
      , propertyType: paVer_.propertyType
      , closeDate: paVer_.closeDate
      , purchasePrice: paVer_.purchasePrice
    })
  } 

  onSubmit() {

  }  



      constructor(private fieldService: sbDocFieldAPI
                  , private sbDFservice: sbDocFieldService
                  , private fb: FormBuilder) {
        var i: number;
        i = 3;
      }

      ngOnInit() {

        this.getAllDocFields();
        //this.patchControls(this.paVer);  clearly the wrong place for this call.

      }
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@mirokoczka/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb

article here talks about adding an @Input() reference in the List pointing to the Detail.   To make this work I would need to wrap List and Detail in another component.... I am going to work on that...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 'learn how to reference child controls', then call methods on the child control.

This page gives 3 good ideas on how to facilitate inter-component communication beyond the @input() method. None really addressed my situation... but they are 3 good ideas that work.
https://medium.com/@mirokoczka/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb

I realized there must be a way to reference other components directly in angular. I found this article about @ViewComponent
https://alligator.io/angular/viewchild-access-component/

This page is a very good article on using @ViewComponent and works through 3 different examples. Very illustrative. Nice work.
https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-viewchild-example

Ultimately the answer is to change the listcomponent so that it has a reference to the child detailcomponent. This is done using the @ViewComponent decorator as follows

```
export class propertyAnalysisListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{

  listFormGroup: FormGroup; 
  paVers: propertyAnalysisVersion[];
  selectedpaVer: propertyAnalysisVersion;

  @ViewChild(propertyAnalysisDetailComponent)
  private myDetail: propertyAnalysisDetailComponent;
```

It's important to note (took me some fumbling to realize) that the final two lines are in fact 1 line.

The  declaration/type is being decorated w/ the @ViewChild.

The detail component is now addressable in the tr.click method of the documentList component

```
  onRowClicked(evt: MouseEvent, paVer: propertyAnalysisVersion) {
    //alert(paVer.versionName);
    this.selectedpaVer = paVer;
    this.myDetail.patchControls(paVer);  //set control values w/ the new data object
  }
}
```

hope this helps someone else.